# jQuery DataTables with Codeigniter not displaying the data

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I'm building an administration panel app using Codeigniter and would like to fetch my member records using the Server Side Processing method of jQuery DataTables (since i've got quite a large number of member records). I'm using the [Ignited DataTables](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/) CI library to fetch and attempt to display my data. I was able to get this working with the standalone version of Datatables Server Side Implementation found [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html), but would like to get this working with CodeIgniter in order to be in line with the rest of my app. Here's my code so far:

CI Controller:

```
$this->load->library('DataTables');
$this->load->model('table_model', 'table');

$this->datatables->select('member_id, username,email, first_name, last_name')
                 ->from($this->table->getTable('members'))
                 ->join($this->table->getTable('groups'), 'members.group_id = member_groups.group_id', 'left')
                 ->select('group_title');

echo $this->datatables->generate();
exit;
```

HTML:

```
<table id="members">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Member ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Group Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty">Loading members...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#members").dataTable({
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "/members/fetch_members",
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
    });
});
```

JSON response:

```
{
    "sEcho": 0,
    "iTotalRecords": 11007,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 11007,
    "aaData": [ //member records here],
    "sColumns": "member_id,username,email,first_name,last_name,group_title"
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: 11007 records are rather a lot, no? Have you tried testing it with fewer (say, 100)? It might be overloading DataTables.

Comment: I figured it out...the IgnitedDataTables library was only checking for $_POST data and my script was sending the parameters as $_GET data.I modified the library to check for both input streams (`$this->ci->input->get_post()`). Hope this helps other people who are stuck down the road.

Comment: @EricPaulsen: Feel free to post (and accept) your answer below for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: I`m facing the same issue, what line did you change or you replaced all $this->ci->input->post() to $this->ci->input->get_post()? i did the later but the result was only two rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the library to work with POST instead of GET

or

You have to configure datatable to work with GET

here is an example of configuring method, use it to suit your need

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/post.html